AWS Cognito Hosted UI
I am facing an error related to a Cognito Hosted UI for login in AWS. On AWS Cognito Hosted UI, after login it shows "Invalid parameter in request".
Note: This is not mismatch redirect uri error
Image Attached
It should actually redirect to callback url

Maybe you selected additional "Required attributes/Additional required attributes" when creating the user pool.

How this flag might affect the result?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
